# Reading .txt File into a Hashmap and manipulating it

Tags: java, file-io, hashmap

Most likely my biggest problem here is not fully understanding Hashmaps and how to manipulate them despite looking at some tutorials.  Hopefully you wise souls will be able to point me in the right track.

I'm trying to read a .txt file into a hashmap.  The text file contains the popularity of names for 2006.  Each line of the inputFile contains a boys name and a girls name as well as how many were named that.  For example: 1     Jacob   24,797  Emily   21,365 would be the input from the file for line 1.

I want to put the boys name into one list, and the girls names into a second list maintaining their current positions so that the user can search for jacob and be told it was the number 1 boys name that year, and so on for other names.  Previously I was just reading the file line by line and seeing what line the file contained the name i was searching for.  This worked, but it was unable to tell if it was a boys name or a girls name, resulting in errors where if I said i was searching for how popular Jacob was for girls, it would still say number 1.  I determined a hashmap would be the best way around this, but can't really get it working.

My Code

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //Parse Input Fields
        String name = inputArea.getText();
        if (name.equals(""))
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A name is required.", "Alert", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE );
            return;
        }
        String genderSelected = genderList.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String yearSelected = yearList.getSelectedItem().toString();

        String yearFile = "Babynamesranking"+yearSelected+".txt";    //Opens a different name file depending on year selection    
        boolean foundName = false;
        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String,String>(); //Creates Hashmap

        try
        {
            File inputFile = new File(yearFile);                    //Sets input file to whichever file chosen in GUI
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(inputFile);      //Creates a fileReader to open the inputFile
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fileReader);     //Creates a buffered reader to read the fileReader

            String line;
            int lineNum = 1;                                        //Incremental Variable to determine which line the name is found on
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (line.contains(name))
                {
                    outputArea.setText(""+name+" was a popular name during "+yearSelected+".");
                    outputArea.append("\nIt is the "+lineNum+" most popular choice for "+genderSelected+" names that year.");
                    foundName = true;
                }
                String parts[] = line.split("\t");
                map.put(parts[0],parts[1]);

                lineNum++;
            }
            fileReader.close();
        }
        catch(IOException exception)
        {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }

        String position = map.get(name);
        System.out.println(position);
}
```

Sample inputFile:

```
1   Jacob   24,797  Emily   21,365
2   Michael 22,592  Emma    19,092
3   Joshua  22,269  Madison     18,599
4   Ethan   20,485  Isabella    18,200
5   Matthew 20,285  Ava     16,925
6   Daniel  20,017  Abigail     15,615
7   Andrew  19,686  Olivia  15,474
8   Christopher 19,635  Hannah  14,515
```

Comment: Is it always the case that it's a boy's name followed by a girl's name, or they could be reversed?

Comment: That is always the case

Comment: If(boy is chosen) look at parts[0] else look at parts[1].

Comment: so that the hashmap contains {name,popularity} pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem is that by using

```
if (line.contains(name))
```

You're checking if the name exists in the whole line, regarding if it's a boy's name or a girl's name. What you can do is to read them separately, then decide which value you want to check. You can do something like this:

```
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(line);
    int lineNumber = sc.nextInt();
    String boyName = sc.next();
    int boyNameFreq = sc.nextInt();
    String girlName = sc.next();
    int girlNameFreq = sc.nextInt();

    if(genderSelected.equals("male") && name.equals(boyName)){
        // .. a boy's name is found
    }
    else if(genderSelected.equals("female") && name.equals(girlName)){
        // .. a girl's name is found
    }

}
```

Scanner class is used to parse the line, and read it token-by-token, so you can know if the name is for a boy or girl. Then check on the name that you need only.

Comment: Rather than two ifs, would make more sense to use if{}else if{}.

Comment: No, because every condition that won't satisfy if {} will execute the else statement. So in case you have a name that doesn't match with the boy name, it'll execute the else block directly even if it doesn't match the girl name either, because you're not checking that condition in the else statement.

Comment: This looks like it may get me around using a hashmap.  Though, I did have a run time error originally with what you had.  it compiled but crashed on execution.  Had to change the int's to doubles.

Comment: @Islam Hassan: If the first condition already met, why check the second condition? it is a bad practice.

Comment: @Justiciar weird. I tried it and it should work fine with integers, unless you have very large numbers (more that 2 billions). What does the error message say when crashing?

Comment: @ndlu I saw your edited comment. If you mean if{} else if{} rather than if{} else {} it should be fine. However you might have a name which is valid for both boys and girls (e.g. a name like Alex or Andy could be used for both genders), then you might want to report them both, according to your use case.

Comment: @Islam Hassan: and what you are saying isn't true, because it could only either by boy or girl, but not both (it's based on gender, remember).

Comment: @ndlu https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unisex_name, however it's a special case. You can have an input line like this 1 Ashley 12,345 Ashley 67,890. If you're certain this won't ever happen, feel free to ignore it.

Comment: @Islam Hassan: I'm talking about the op's code, genderSelected.

Comment: @ndlu ok my bad. You can add else if

Answer (score 0):

You'll want two hashmaps, one for boys' names and one for girls' names - at present you're using boys' names as keys and girls' names as values, which is not what you want.  Instead, use two `Map<String, IntTuple>` data structures where the `String` is the name and the `IntTuple` is the line number (rank) and the count of people with this name.

```
class IntTuple {
  final int rank;
  final int count;

  IntTuple(int rank, int count) {
    this.rank = rank;
    this.count = count;
  }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense.  I was a little confused by the "keys".  I will play with that in the code

Comment: Based on his code it is not necessary to create two hashmaps, because the front end user has already chosen the sex, therefore only need one hashmap.

Comment: @Justiciar The key is what you use to look up the value, for example if your hash map contains the "Jacob" key mapped to the "1, 24,797" IntTuple value then "map.get("Jacob")" would return the "1, 24,797" value